# torify links returning "host not found"

Tags: tor

I'm running Ubuntu. Installed tor with 'sudo apt-get install tor' and also installed 'links.'

I tried running links with tor using: 'torify links'

The program loads but when I try and go anywhere it returns a 'Host not found' error.

Links works fine without 'torify' and sites are all accessible. I can also ping sites using the ping command, no problem.

Does tor not work with links? Do I need to configure something?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a really old version that is provided by Ubuntu and it's returning errors like:

> libtorsocks(5389): WARNING: The symbol res_query() was not found in
>   any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!   Also, we
>   failed to find the symbol __res_query() with the reported error: Not
>   Found

The solution I'd try is to just build the latest version from source and use that.

```
sudo apt-get remove torsocks
git clone https://git.torproject.org/torsocks.git
cd torsocks
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

However, that didn't seem to help with `links`.  It still fails to resolve names and I'm not able to get it working using Proxychains either (it does resolve DNS over Tor but somehow it fails to get back to links).

I think the solution may be to use `links`'s SOCKS proxy option (it didn't leak DNS for me).

```
links -socks-proxy 127.0.0.1:9050 https://example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for that last tip about using links' SOCKS proxy.

Comment: I ended up just using 'lynx' instead of 'links.' I prefer the latter but at least I have a functional terminal browser using tor now with 'torsocks lynx' Thanks!